# I mistakenly deposit my BTC to my BCC address. How can i get it back?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, lost-transactions, cross-chain-recovery, hitbtc

I intended to withdraw BTC from my Yobit.net account, and send it to my BTC address of HitBTC.com account.
But, unfortunately, by my critical mistake, I sent it to my BCC address of HitBTC.com account. This transaction already went through 6 confirms, and the message in Yobit.net indicates that transaction was completed, but there is no deposit in my BTC as well as BCC account in HitBTC.com
Because it's an address of HitBTC.com, I don't have a private key for that BCC address.
I sent e-mails to Yobit.net, and HitBTC.com, but haven't received any response yet. Is there anyone who know I can get my BTC back? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to contact HitBTC and ask them to correct it. In theory they have the private keys and can recover these coins in a way similar to splitting Bcash and Bitcoin in the first place, but prudent security practices may make this difficult for them to do.

You might also want to contact the creators of BCash and point out to them how this decision to use addresses which are indistinguishable from Bitcoin has caused you problems. This was a conscious choice on their part and has resulted in funds losses for a number of people, just as Litcoin's similar mistake years ago with P2SH addresses caused.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I e-mailed to HitBTC, but still waiting for response.